# Swift how to get different types as paramaters? Enums vs Switch case?

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring, alamofire

I have three different data fetching methods like the following sample. Three different methods should return different decodable types. The only difference between these methods is the Type that they would be parsed into. Obviously three different methods is just code duplication.

It works that way but I want to simplify and refactor that methods. I have three different response types. I guess I need to use switch case with some enum or use enums as parameters. But I don't know how to do that.

```
func fetchProducts(with parameters: CategoryParams, completion: @escaping (ProductsResponse) -> Void) {
        AF.request(productURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: ProductsResponse.self) { res in
        switch res.result {
        case .success:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(res.value!)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you need is a generic method. Then you can just explicitly set the resulting type.

Answer (score 1):

Generic! you should input the specific type that you want to decode.

```swift
func fetchProducts<RespType>(with parameters: CategoryParams, respType: RespType.Type, completion: @escaping (RespType) -> Void) {
  AF.request(productURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: RespType.self) { res in
    switch res.result {
    case .success:
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(res.value!)
      }
    case .failure(let error):
      print(error)
    }
  }
}
```